# Find the probability density function for 2 random variables

Tags: density-function

I have a question and I will be happy to get some help.
$X$ and $Y$ are random variables that are distributed uniformly in $(0,1)$ (Continuous Uniform distribution).
**EDIT: X and Y are independent**
$W$ is defined as $X^2 - Y$. What is the probability density function of $W$? Similarly, $Z$ is defined as $X + Y$. What is the probability density function of $Z$?

I tried to calculate $\Pr(W<w)$ by using the definition of $W$ and calculating $\Pr(X^2 -Y < w)$ by calculating the double integral. Finally, to find the pdf, I differentiated the expression. I did the same for $Z$
but I am not sure about the results I have got (mainly how to determine the limits of the result). For example I have got for $W: f(w) = \sqrt{1+w} - \sqrt{w}$

thanks :)

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ independent?

Comment: yes
forgot to mention that